# Class attributes are not working in typescript (angular). How can I fix this?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am learning to use angular, CSS(tailwind), HTML, and typescript to build a website.

I click the menu button in the navbar 3 times but why was `this.name` underdefined the first time the button was clicked?

**How `this.name` gets the HTML name the first time the menu button is clicked ?** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVbPx.jpg)

**top-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component,OnInit } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector:'app-top-bar',
    templateUrl:'./top-bar.component.html'

})

export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor() {

    }
    ngOnInit() {

    }

    menu(e:any) {
        console.log(e)
        console.log(e.name)

        let list:any = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
            let menu_on:any = document.querySelector('#menu-on');
            let menu_off:any = document.querySelector('#menu-off');
            if (e.name == "menu") {
                e.name = "close";
                list.classList.remove('hidden');
                menu_on.classList.add('hidden');
                menu_off.classList.remove('hidden');
            } else {
                e.name = "menu";
                list.classList.add('hidden');
                menu_off.classList.add('hidden');
                menu_on.classList.remove('hidden');
            }
    }

    dropdown(e:any) {

        let list:any = document.querySelector('#user-dropdown');
        if (e.name == 'dropdown') {
            e.name = "close";
            list.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            e.name = "dropdown";
            list.classList.add('hidden');
        }

    }

}
```

**top-bar.component.html**

```
<nav class="bg-gray-800">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-6 flex items-center justify-between h-16">
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0 px-3">
                <img class="h-8 w-8" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-500.svg" alt="Workflow">
            </div>
            <div class="hidden md:block">
                <a href="" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Dashboard</a>
                <a href="" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Team</a>
                <a href="" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Projects</a>
                <a href="" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Calendar</a>
                <a href="" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Reports</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="hidden md:block">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="mx-4 flex items-center">
                    <button class="bg-gray-800 p1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white">
                    <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
                </div>

                <div class="flex items-center relative">
                    <button type="button" class="bg-gray-800 rounded-full active:ring-2 active:ring-white" (click)="dropdown(this)" name="dropdown">
                    <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
                </button>
                    <div id="user-dropdown" class="bg-white absolute right-0 mt-40 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 z-10 hidden">
                        <a href="" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700">Your Profile</a>
                        <a href="" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700">Settings</a>
                        <a href="" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700">Sign out</a>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- button -->
        <div class="md:hidden">
            <!-- ################# this line ################# -->
            <button type="button" class="bg-gray-800 items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700" name="menu" (click)="menu(this)">
                <!--  ################################## -->
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id='menu-on' fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                </svg>
                <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id='menu-off' fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
              </button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- mobile menu -->
    <div class="md:hidden hidden" id="mobile-menu">
        <div class="px-6 py-2">
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Team</a>
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Calendar</a>
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Reports</a>
        </div>

        <div class="flex items-center px-9 border-t border-gray-700 pt-4">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="mx-3">
                <div class="text-base font-medium leading-none text-white">Tom Cook</div>
                <div class="text-sm font-medium leading-none text-gray-400">tom@example.com</div>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-auto">
                <button class="bg-gray-800 p1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-white">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
                </svg>
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="px-6 py-4">
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Your Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Setting</a>
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Sign out</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `dropdown(this)` in template, you need to call `dropdown($event)`. `this` refers to the instance of the component here. And to retrieve the `name` property you need to do `e.target.name` in component method.

What is happening in your case is, in the first case when you log `e` it logs the component instance itself and you assign something like `e.name="dropdown"` so what you basically are doing is adding a property `name` to the instance of that component dynamically which is not ideal.

And the other thing, using `document.querySelector` is not ideal as either. You can use template reference variable using `#` keyword in template and get the reference to that using `ViewChild` in the component.